# SSL_get_ex_new_index openssl usage for storing per SSL * data

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a requirement where I need to store data per ssl session, I was thinking of using the SSL_get_ex_new_index and storing in that idx. Note: The data would be different for each SSL *.

Can the get_ex api be used for this purpose. If not, is there any other way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your use case is not quite clear. If you only need to associate local data with the local SSL object inside the current process then this is a possible way. If you need to associate data with the TLS session itself (and not only with the current SSL object) or even need to keep the data associated even if a new process re-established the old TLS session then this is not the way to go. It might help if you describe your actual requirement in more depth.

Comment: @Steffen: I only want to associate it with a local SSL object. So ii think this should work. Thanks.